# Microsoft Access -> SQL Server - blank/default Schema

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, ms-access

we have a large MS Access application which uses SQL Server for the database (about 200 tables).

We want to convert it to a multi-tenancy database, where we will have a single large SQL Server database. Inside the database each client will have their own set of tables in their own schema. Eg, ten clients using database - ten Schemas in that database.

We will then migrate it to Azure and run the MS Access application as an Azure RemoteApp.

We want to create an Active Directory User Group for each client, and map it across to the default SQL Server Schema for that client.

The idea is that new users are added to the relevant AD User Group, and by default get mapped across to the right Schema with their data,

The problem we have is the MS Access Linked Tables contain a hard-coded explicit Schema (dbo by default).

Can anyone think of a way to store a "Source"/external/linked table in MS Access without having to specify a Schema. Eg. just "tblSales", not "dbo.tblSales".

Answer (score 0):

A typical relink code goes like this (a snip only):

```
For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
    strName = tdf.Name
    If Asc(strName) <> Asc("~") Then
        If InStr(tdf.Connect, cstrDbType) = 1 Then
            tdf.Connect = strConnect
            tdf.RefreshLink
            Debug.Print Timer, tdf.Name, tdf.SourceTableName, tdf.Connect
            DoEvents
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I have no other schema than dbo to test with, and I'm not sure if the property *SourceTableName* is read-only. If not, it could be adjusted:

```
For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
    strName = tdf.Name
    If Asc(strName) <> Asc("~") Then
        If InStr(tdf.Connect, cstrDbType) = 1 Then
            tdf.Connect = strConnect
            tdf.SourceTableName = strNewSchema & "." & Split(tdf.SourceTableName, ".")(1)
            tdf.RefreshLink
            Debug.Print Timer, tdf.Name, tdf.SourceTableName, tdf.Connect
            DoEvents
        End If
    End If
Next
```

If it is read-only, you will have to delete the linked table and recreate the link.

That said, I'm not sure if your idea of a schema for each client is such a good idea. We had similar considerations and decided simply to create a database for each client. If for nothing else, backup and restore clientwise is greatly simplified.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

We want to have a single copy of the application code with a single database for many clients.

It's not really practical or efficient to have multiple copies of the Access code, each with a different external database linkage, With 200 tables it wouldn't be practical either to Relink for every login either.

Using Schemas to support a multi-tenancy database should work, we just need a way to figure out how to handle it from the MS Access front end.

Comment: You seem a bit confused. You will need one frontend only in any case, but you will have to relink this once for each client no matter if it should link to a specific schema or a specific database. When (re)linked to a specific schema or database, the frontend stays so no matter how many times the user logs on. Simple relink code is available for the browsing, though for a real-life application you will prefer to wrap it with decent forms and error handling.